# How to get document root in sailsjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

To read a file located in the document root of the sails project I currently use an absolute path.

```
/var/www/project/file.conf
```

How can I get the document root path in sails? Or how can I read the file in a controller by using relative path?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the main application file is `app.js` in the root folder, [`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process%5fprocess%5fcwd) should work just fine for you.

Answer (score 17):

in Sails the root path is: sails.config.appPath

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BlakesSeven Actually it does answer - in sails the results of sails.config.appPath and process.cwd() are exactly the same, the first is sails specific and the later is general for node js. The question was about Sailsjs not node.

Answer (score 2):

To extend what @Maciej Maczor Kaczorowski posted...

```
var path = require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'file.conf');
```

or

```
var path = require('path').resolve(".", 'file.conf');
```

or

```
var path = require('path').resolve('file.conf');
```

or

```
var path = sails.config.appPath + 'file.conf';
```

or

```
var path = res.baseUrl + 'file.conf';
```